# How to combine INDEX, IFERROR and VLOOKUP formulas

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I would like to Index a columns info, run a `vlookup` of a particular text(s) and then perform an if error to ignore things not like the "lookup value". I have data in column V called "Biscuits" amongst other items of different names.  "Biscuits" has to be replaced with a different name. But the name change will not be the same for each occurrence.  I would like to maintain the original column V's data and Index that particular columns values into another column.  Once I have created a "copy" of the original data named column AV, I then need to run a `vlookup` on column AV.  I have a column AW that has manual information of different names inputted in this column.  In the "Indexed" Column AV I would like to run `vlookup` on "Biscuits" ONLY, skipping other entries and replace "Biscuits" with the contents of column AW (all entries in Column AW for name changes are on the same lines as "Biscuits"

Example

[Original Column, Indexed Column, Manual input column and final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9oqM.jpg)

```
=INDEX(V2, ,)-this is the formula I wrote to Index column V, thus creating column AV
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Biscuits",V2:AW2,28,FALSE),"")-This is a formula I wrote to look for "Biscuits" and replace it with the contents of column AW
```

Please help on this.

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded a image of the process and what the end result would look like.

Comment: Thank you for the formula! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

According to OP *It worked!*, the formula being:

```
=IF(AW2="",V2,AW2)
```

Ie return the contents of V2 if AW2 is empty and the contents of AW2 otherwise. This can be copied down to apply to other rows, with references adjusting automatically. Neither the 'index column' nor any of INDEX, IFERROR or VLOOKUP were required.